# Write to output stream and read from input stream PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve something like i can write to some stream and read from input stream such as

```
$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($fh, 'Hello World');
$input = file_get_contents('php://input'); // outputs ""
```

I understand that when we write to output stream it basically prints out the stuff and never reach to the point where `php://input` can have the data. But I could not find any example to achieve this.

Basically I want to test something based on the data received from input steam but not sure how to give data to input stream.

Thanks

Comment: from the manual: " `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives." So, _give_ data to the input stream through $_POST data (e.g. form or cURL).

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to read from php://input, you might need to look at stream_get_contents or other things that work on streams such as fread() and fwrite() etc.

Ref:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php